# Last row replaced when databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

This must be very simple but yet i cannt find an answer.

So i create a data table that filled with some values, the i add a new row, bind the data and it shows perfectly. However, when i try to add the second row (manually) it replaces the first one instead of adding a new row to the data table.

```
private DataTable dtProd = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            dtProd.Columns.Add("Des");
            dtProd.Columns.Add("Quant");

            dtProd.Rows.Add("Lixivia", "10");
            dtProd.Rows.Add("Bolachas", "5");
            dtProd.Rows.Add("Papel", "15");

            GridView1.DataSource = dtProd;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    protected void BTNAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtProd.Rows.Add(TBDes.Text, TBQuant.Text);
        TBDes.Text = "";
        TBQuant.Text = "0";
        GridView1.DataBind();
        TBDes.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding rows to a DataTable, you should use `NewRow()` method:

```
DataRow dtr = dtProd.NewRow();
dtr["Des"] = TBDes.Text;
dtr["Quant"] = TBQuant.Text;
dtr.Rows.Add(dtr);
```

You can check MSDN for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx

Comment: It does exactelly the same thing as my code, but its mostly used when using a dataadapter or a dataset. So the result was unfortunatelly the same.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSousa That is certainly the way to add rows to a DataTable. I suspect your grid datasource is not being refreshed and that is the problem

Comment: If its not being refreshed how can i see the last row i just added? The refresh is causing the data loss as far as i can see